# How to hide a Vaadin 7 UI embedded on a non-Vaadin page?

Tags: html, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm embedding a Vaadin application within a non-Vaadin web page, using a the "div" technique, as described in https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.embedding.html

I'd like to completely hide the Vaadin UI in some circumstances and show at other times.

Is this possible **from within the Vaadin app** and if so, how?

We've looked at:

- JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("document.getElementById('my_vaadin_div').style.display = 'none';"); - Works but not pure Java...
- GWT's DOM.getElementById("my_vaadin_div").setAttribute("display", "none"); - Doesn't work probably because DOM is client side GWT.

Answer (score 0):

I think your second option is the way to go. You want to hide the `div` that contains your Vaadin app, so here you have a pure client side manipulation. You can do that with GWT to stay in the realm of Java. Of course, you can't execute the GWT code you proposed directly from the server side. But you can write a [component extension](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/gwt.extension.html) which you can use to extend your UI instance. Using a `ClientRPC` you can switch the `div` on or off.